# I got an error of python flask htmlTemplateSyntaxError

Tags: python, jinja2

I have studied python flask.
I look into programs and googled a lot of times.

The code are as follows;

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>New User Registration</title>
</head>
<body>
   {% extends "detector/base.html" %}
   {% block title %} New User Registration {% endblock %}
   {% block content %}
      <div class="mx-auto dt-auth-main">
         <div class="card dt-auth-signup">
            <header>New User Registration</header>
            <section>
               <form method="post" action="{{url_for('auth.signup', next=request.args.get('next')) }}" class="form-signin">
                  {{ form.csrf_token}}
                  {% for message in get_flashed_messages() %}
                  <div class="dt-auth-flash">{{ message }}</div>
                  { % endfor %}
                  {{ form.username(size=20, class="form-control dt-auth-input", placeholder="username")}}
                  {{ form.email(class="form-control dt-auth-input", placeholder="mailaddress")}}
                  {{ form.password(class="form-control dt-auth-input", placeholder="password")}} 
                  {{ form.submit(class="btn btn-md btn-primary btn-block dt-auth-btn") }}  
               </form>
            </section>
         </div>
      </div>
   {% endblock%}
      
</body>
</html>
```

I got the following error.
jinja2.exceptions.TemplateSyntaxError: Encountered unknown tag 'endblock'. You probably made a nesting mistake. Jinja is expecting this tag, but currently looking for 'endfor' or 'else'. The innermost block that needs to be closed is 'for'.

Please give me kind help.

Comment: Without following codes, it works;{% for message in get_flashed_messages() %}
                  <div class="dt-auth-flash">{{ message }}</div>
                  { % endfor %}

Comment: Maybe, get_flashed_messages() have problems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a typo on the line with `{ % endfor %}` (Line 21).
You have to delete the space between { and % like `{% endfor %}`
It didn't work because it waits that the `{% for %}` is closed